# How Get Id of Draggable Element Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, drag-and-drop

I need to get an ID of the draggable Element

I'm using ng2_dnd I tried in method OnDragStart to get ID like this

```
  <li dnd-draggable [dropZones]="['doc']" [dragEnabled]="true" id="id01" (onDragStart)="getDraggableId($event)">Div 12</li>
```

and in typescript side I call my method getDraggableId

```
getDraggableId(event){
        this.draggableIdGrid = $(event).attr('id');
        console.log("get draggablke  " + this.draggableIdGrid);

    }
```

should I use ElementRef ?

thanks

Comment: You probably already have the element id or the element reference in the event variable. Maybe try and check it out with `console.log(event)`.

Comment: When I show event I get  [object object ]

and when I show the Id event.target.attributes.id I get error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd/blob/master/src/dnd.draggable.ts#L93) I came to the conclusion that this should work:

```
getDraggableId(event){
    this.draggableIdGrid = event.mouseEvent.target.id;
    console.log("get draggable  " + this.draggableIdGrid);
}
```